# when i call stored procedure using mybatis , how to make returned results strings not map?

Tags: spring-mybatis

I call sp using mybatis ,

when i define functions like that

```
void submitTransactions(@Param("transactions") List<Transaction> transaction, 
@Param("response") Map<String,String> res);
```

===========================================================================

```
<select id="submitTransactions" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="map" >
     {call MANAGE_APP_TRANSACTIONS(
         NULL, --P_MSG_ID
         NULL, --P_SC_ID
         'ManageAppTransaction', --P_FUN_ID
         'ONLINE', --P_USER_ID
         'E', --P_PREF_LANG
         NULL, --P_RQ_MODE
         NULL, --P_CLIENT_DATE
         NULL, --P_VERSION
         #{response.responseStatus,javaType=String,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=OUT},  --P_STATUS_CODE
         #{response.statusDesc,javaType=String,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=OUT}, --P_STATUS_DESC

         #{transactions,javaType=List,jdbcType=ARRAY,mode=IN,jdbcTypeName=APP_TRANSACTION_ARRAY,typeHandler=com.ejada.staripo.dao.TransactionArrayTypeHandler} --P_APP_TRNS_LIST
    )}
</select>
```

responseStatus and statusDesc return correctly ,but when i define functions like that

```
void submitTransactions(@Param("transactions") List<Transaction> transaction, 
@Param("responseStatus") String responseStatus , @Param("statusDesc") String 
statusDesc);
```

===========================================================================

```
</select>
    <select id="submitTransactions" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="map" resultType="java.lang.String">
     {call MANAGE_APP_TRANSACTIONS(
         NULL, --P_MSG_ID
         NULL, --P_SC_ID
         'ManageAppTransaction', --P_FUN_ID
         'ONLINE', --P_USER_ID
         'E', --P_PREF_LANG
         NULL, --P_RQ_MODE
         NULL, --P_CLIENT_DATE
         NULL, --P_VERSION
         #{responseStatus,javaType=String,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=OUT},  --P_STATUS_CODE
         #{statusDesc,javaType=String,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=OUT}, --P_STATUS_DESC

         #{transactions,javaType=List,jdbcType=ARRAY,mode=IN,jdbcTypeName=APP_TRANSACTION_ARRAY,typeHandler=com.ejada.staripo.dao.TransactionArrayTypeHandler} --P_APP_TRNS_LIST
    )}
</select>
```

responseStatus and statusDesc doesnot return ,why?

Answer (score 0):

Where you call `submitTransactions`, you pass 2 variables (likely null, but whatever) for output params. So how would a variable declared in outer scope could be updated from inner scope? This is not C++ with String *.
Indirection is required, that's why you need to provide the map (or any object), to keep a pointer on target of the output param.

Comment: first thank you for your answer :) , second i understood from your answer that i must pass pointer to the funtion
    void submitTransactions(@Param("transactions") List<Transaction> transaction, 
    @Param("responseStatus") String responseStatus , @Param("statusDesc") 
    String statusDesc);

so if i pass object like that
  String statusCode=new String();
  String StatusDesc=new String();
is that right ?(i allready did that and don't work) or you mean another thing?

Comment: no, I meant, you have to pass a "container" (a map or any custom object with required properties). procedure output parameters work as side effect: change the state of the container, that is then read from the program side.